# Can Django's multiple database and routing be used to sync data across databases

Tags: mysql, django

I have 2 different mysql database (OLD and NEW) running in different servers. OLD Database has around 10 tables out of which i want to synchronize 3 tables database NEW. So if any addition/deletion/updation happens on those 3 tables then those entries should be updated on database NEW. I have created the NEW database using the mysql dump.

Can the above be achieved by using django multiple database and routing?
I was planning for:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {},
'OLD': {
    'NAME': 'user_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'superS3cret'
},
'NEW': {
    'NAME': 'customer_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_cust',
    'PASSWORD': 'veryPriv@ate'
}
```

}

then have a PrimaryReplicaRouter similar to one defined in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

Then I can query for data from OLD which have changes after last sycned time and then save to NEW. I'm not sure if that would work for purpose of sycning data? and also if it would be faster than performing the sync using mysqldump every 1 hour in cron?

Answer (score 1):

### Is it worth it?

Are you sure this is not a case of premature optimization. This sort of effort is only worth if you have lots of heavy queries or a large number of concurrent users. If you do read on,

### Don't dump and import

mysqldump and import is definitely not the way to go. If you have a lot of data to justify the use of multi-db, your dump is going to take a long time. The import is going to take longer. While the import is happening the tables will be locked. Which means all your read operations are halted.

### mysql replication

This is the only practical way to use two databases.

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be copied to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous by default; slaves do not need to be
>   connected permanently to receive updates from the master. Depending on
>   the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected
>   databases, or even selected tables within a database.

more details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

This can be used concurrently with Django database routers. You can have one DB for reading and keep the other for writing. Copying data between the two is take care of by mysql replication in a fast and efficient manner.